# IOS: UITextView rotated iOS 7 wrap text

Tags: ios, uitextview, ios7

in my app I need a textview that I'll show when the phone turn in landscape orientation; this is my code to have a perfect UItextView rotated for the landscape.

```
textview_right.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/2);
```

in iOS 6 it's perfect but in iOS 7 textview wrap text after a word and I don't see my text. why?

I show you two shot:

- this is normal in portrait

[image]

- it's not normal

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLUTION:**

put UITextView inside a UIView and rotate it, simply.